# How to create inline reference to all preceding items?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, descriptive-grammar

I need to create a list of items where each item is associated with a descriptive clause that comes at the end of the list. One way to accomplish this is with formatting. E.g.,

> If Client does not pay, Provider may immediately suspend Client's account which may include:
>
> 1. revoking user access;
> 2. suspending any open campaigns; and
> 3. excluding Client's content
>
> in connection to the purchased services.

Each numbered clause should be read in conjunction with the "flush language" (i.e., the descriptive clause at the end of the list). So "revoking user access ... in connection with the purchased services." The question is, if I wanted to do this all inline (with no indents or formatting tricks) what punctuation would be best?

Comment: Don't understand why *formatting* is necessary to *accomplish this* or how that relates to or leads into your example. Also, don't understand what *inline* means in the context of your question. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other form of editing, correction, or style change, your presentation can be turned into a single sentence in a couple of ways:

> 1. If Client does not pay, Provider may immediately suspend Client's account, which may include the following in connection to the purchased services: revoking user license, suspending any open campaign, and excluding Client's content.
> 2. If Client does not pay, Provider may immediately suspend Client's account, which may include, in connection to the purchased services, revoking user license, suspending any open campaign, and excluding Client's content.

Comment: One of those simple and elegant solutions that when you see it makes you wonder: "why didn't I think of that?" Excellent! Thank you.